# iPhone NSURLConnection pop-up for entering user/password requested?

Tags: iphone, authorization, nsurlconnection

I observed in a Hotel I am that when other apps trying to access the internet a pop-up appears that ask the iPhone user to enter the user id and password of the Hotel's Wireless LAN. I guess it is some kind of redirect on all requests to protect misuse of the WLAN.

I have an app and it does use the NSURLConnection but I am not getting the pop-up instead it goes via the regular data network of the carrier. I removed the SIM to see what happens then and then the connection fails with an error "The Internet connection appears to be offline".

I wonder whether this is because the NSURLConnection does not provide such a pop-up and this other apps (e.g. Safari, e.g. WhatsApp) use a different API. One the other hand I thought that might be what the documentation says is the "Authorization Challenge". I have implemented those delegate methods but they are not called.

If someone with some experience on this can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the documentation for the UIRequiresPersistentWiFi Info.plist key - there are some tradeoffs (users will get an alert every time they open your application if their phone is in Airplane Mode - doesn't seem to be any way to turn that off) but that should force it to make the connection.

Comment: That did the trick. Surfing a bit I see posts where people talk about SBUsesNetwork in the plist but no mention of the property in the apple documentation. Is this an old value or should I better use it as it is "undocumented"?

Comment: It's undocumented but I don't believe Apple has a problem with it (lots of people use it) - if things work fine without it I'd probably leave it out, though, you never know when their policy might change.